# AMP autocomplete how get id from autocomplete results and display only text in input

Tags: autocomplete, amp-html

[view screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRQtq.png) I am using https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-autocomplete/ and I am able show in results id and name concated in one string, but I need show only name and store id in hidden input.
[code screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zngte.png)

```
        <amp-autocomplete filter="substring" filter-value="name" min-characters="2" src="/ajax/get_active_clinics.php" class="name_autocomplete">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Numele clinicii" name="clinic_name" id="clinic_name"
               {literal}on="change:AMP.setState({clinic_name_validation: true, form_message_validation:true})"{/literal}>
        <span class="hide"
              [class]="formResponse.clinic_name && !clinic_name_validation ? 'show input_validation_error' : 'hide'">Clinica este obligatorie</span>

        <template type="amp-mustache" id="amp-template-custom">
            {literal}
                <div class="city-item" data-value="ID - {{id}}, {{name}}">
                    <div class="autocomplete-results-item-holder">
                        <div class="autocomplete-results-item-img">
                            <amp-img src="{{link}}" alt="{{name}}" width="40" height="40"></amp-img>
                        </div>
                        <div class="autocomplete-results-item-text">{{name}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/literal}
        </template>
    </amp-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `select` event on `amp-autocomplete` to get the event.value which will return the value of the data-value attribute of the selected item.

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-autocomplete/#events

You can then call the split() string method on the result.

You'll need to modify the data-value in your mustache template like so:

```
<div class="city-item" data-value="{{id}},{{name}}">
```

Then add the following code to your autocomplete, this will assign the split values to 2 temporary state properties.

```
<amp-autocomplete
  ...
  on="select: AMP.setState({
    clinicName: event.value.split(',')[0],
    clinicId: event.value.split(',')[1]
  })"
>
```

Once these values are in state you can then access them using bound values. Note the [value] attribute, this will update the inputs value when state changes. It's worth mentioning that the change in value won't trigger the `change` event listener on your input here as it's only triggered on user interaction.

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Numele clinicii"
  name="clinic_name"
  id="clinic_name"
  [value]="clinicName"
  on="change:AMP.setState({
      clinic_name_validation: true,
      form_message_validation:true
    })"
/>
```

Last thing you'll need to do is add the hidden input for Clinic ID, again this will need to be bound to the temporary state property `clinicId`.

```
<input
  type="hidden"
  name="clinic_id"
  [value]="clinicId"
>
```